# Add intermediate text plotly treemap

Tags: python, plotly, treemap

I was able to add some text in the inner squares of the plotly [px.treemap](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.treemap.html) with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67397976/5931672). Basically using:

```
fig.data[0].customdata = whatever
fig.data[0].texttemplate = template whatever
```

However, I would like to add text also to outer squares, a littlebit like this image:

[image]

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: I have no experience with that customization. Does it serve your purpose to have a long string of labels from the beginning? `labels=['Some info<br>Some more info<br>bla bla', ...]`

Comment: Mhm `labels` parameter seems tempting. I tried but it does not work. So either I did not understand what it was or I am using it incorrectly. In any case, the description says it's a dictionary. Do you have an example of how it should work?

Comment: In the example in this [reference](https://plotly.com/python/treemaps/#set-different-attributes-in-treemap), I tried the label in HTML format, like a comment.

Comment: Yes, indeed, it worked. It is a bit nasty because such a long name makes the text super small and in the end I cannot read it... But I guess it is a solution... If you elaborate I could mark as solution. Although if there is a way to keep values big it would be better.
I also profitted I now use `go.Treemap` to use the `text` parameter which is more neat, but still it desapears if there are some 'sons'